# How to set a Start and End point of a picture in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a canvas with some circles drawn inside. Those circles are very important because they let me draw lines. I have some images that the user can drag and drop inside the canvas, but I want to set a start point and an end point to the image so when I drop it inside the canvas the start point stays in the first circle and the end point 2 circles behind.I want the circuits (images) to snap to the holes in the breadboard (grid of circles). ***Something like this but with the dropped image:*** [image]

**

```js
//Javascript per la creazione di cirucuiti elettrici

const NUMERO_CICLO = 990;
const NUMERO_CICLO_INTERNO = 60;

const resistor = document.getElementById('component_circuit_resistor');
const condensator = document.getElementById('component_circuit_condensator');
const tranistor = document.getElementById('component_circuit_tranistor');
const alimentator = document.getElementById('component_circuit_alimentator');
const circuit = document.getElementById('components_circuit');
const back_button = document.getElementById('back-button');
const clear_button = document.getElementById('clear-button');
const draggable = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
const container = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const foward_button = document.getElementById('foward-button');

/** EDIT START */
const draggableImages = document.querySelectorAll('img[draggable]');

for (let i = 0; i < draggableImages.length; i++)
  draggableImages[i].ondragstart = (ev) => {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', i.toString());
  };

canvas.ondragover = (ev) => ev.preventDefault(); // IMPORTANT

const orderStack = [];
const deletedOrderStack = [];

const drawnImageData = [];
const deletedImageData = [];

canvas.ondrop = (ev) => {
  const index = parseInt(ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
  const img = draggableImages[index];
  drawnImageData.push({
    img,
    x: ev.offsetX,
    y: ev.offsetY
  });
  orderStack.push(1);
};
clear_button.disabled = true;
clear_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
foward_button.disabled = true;
foward_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
back_button.disabled = true;
back_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
/** EDIT END */

canvas.width = 1500;
canvas.height = 855;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgrey';
circuit.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.style.borderRadius = '10px';
canvas.style.marginLeft = 'auto';
canvas.style.marginRight = 'auto';
canvas.style.display = 'block';
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const circles = [];
const lines = [];
const lines_c = [];
var deletedLines = [];

for (let y = 20; y <= NUMERO_CICLO; y += 20) {
  for (let i = 0; i < NUMERO_CICLO_INTERNO; i++) {
    circles.push({
      x: 13 + i * 25,
      y,
      radius: 5,
      color: 'grey',
    });
  }
}

let startCircle = null;
let endCircle = null;
var priorita = null;

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  circles.forEach((circle) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = circle.color;
    ctx.fill();
  });
  lines.forEach((line) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.moveTo(line.start.x, line.start.y);
    ctx.lineTo(line.end.x, line.end.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  });
  if (startCircle && endCircle) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.moveTo(startCircle.x, startCircle.y);
    ctx.lineTo(endCircle.x, endCircle.y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  /** EDIT START */
  for (const data of drawnImageData)
    ctx.drawImage(data.img, data.x, data.y, data.img.width, data.img.height);

  /** EDIT END */
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  if (drawnImageData.length > 0 || lines.length > 0) {
    clear_button.disabled = false;
    clear_button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    back_button.disabled = false;
    back_button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  }
}
draw();

function goBack() {
  if (orderStack.length === 0) {
    return
  }

  if (orderStack[orderStack.length - 1] === 1 && drawnImageData.length > 0) {
    deletedImageData.push(drawnImageData.pop());
  } else if (orderStack[orderStack.length - 1] === 0 && lines.length > 0) {
    deletedLines.push(lines.pop());
  }

  deletedOrderStack.push(orderStack.pop())

  // Check if there are any items left to undo
  if (drawnImageData.length === 0 && lines.length === 0) {
    back_button.disabled = true;
    back_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
    clear_button.disabled = true;
    clear_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
  }
  // Enable the forward button
  foward_button.disabled = false;
  foward_button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
}

function goFoward() {
  if (deletedOrderStack.length === 0) {
    return
  }

  if (deletedOrderStack[deletedOrderStack.length - 1] === 1 && deletedImageData.length > 0) {
    drawnImageData.push(deletedImageData.pop());
    orderStack.push(deletedOrderStack.pop());
  } else if (deletedOrderStack[deletedOrderStack.length - 1] === 0 && deletedLines.length > 0) {
    lines.push(deletedLines.pop());
    orderStack.push(deletedOrderStack.pop());
  }
  // Check if there are any items left to redo
  if (deletedImageData.length === 0 && deletedLines.length === 0) {
    foward_button.disabled = true;
    foward_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
  }

  // Enable the back button
  back_button.disabled = false;
  back_button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
}

function clearCanvas() {
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the circuit?')) {
    lines.length = 0;
    deletedLines.length = 0;
    lastDeleted = null;

    // clear drawn images data
    drawnImageData.length = 0;

    orderStack.length = 0
    deletedOrderStack.length = 0

    clear_button.disabled = true;
    clear_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
    foward_button.disabled = true;
    foward_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
    back_button.disabled = true;
    back_button.style.cursor = 'not-allowed';
  }
}

function getNearestCircle(x, y) {
  let nearestCircle = null;
  let nearestDistance = Infinity;
  circles.forEach((circle) => {
    const distance = Math.sqrt((circle.x - x) ** 2 + (circle.y - y) ** 2);
    if (distance < nearestDistance && distance < 30) {
      nearestCircle = circle;
      nearestDistance = distance;
    }
  });
  return nearestCircle;
}

let isDrawing = false;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  const x = event.offsetX;
  const y = event.offsetY;
  const circle = getNearestCircle(x, y);
  if (circle) {
    startCircle = circle;
    endCircle = {
      x,
      y
    };
    isDrawing = true;
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  if (isDrawing) {
    endCircle.x = event.offsetX;
    endCircle.y = event.offsetY;
  } else {
    const x = event.offsetX;
    const y = event.offsetY;
    const circle = getNearestCircle(x, y);
    if (circle) {
      circles.forEach((circle) => {
        circle.color = 'grey';
      });
      circle.color = 'red';
    } else {
      circles.forEach((circle) => {
        circle.color = 'grey';
      });
    }
  }
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  if (isDrawing) {
    const x = endCircle.x;
    const y = endCircle.y;
    const circle = getNearestCircle(x, y);
    if (circle) {
      lines.push({
        start: startCircle,
        end: circle,
      });

      orderStack.push(0);
    }
    isDrawing = false;
    startCircle = null;
    endCircle = null;
  }
});

//back_button.addEventListener("click", goBack);
//foward_button.addEventListener("click", goBack);
clear_button.addEventListener('click', clearCanvas);

var back_clicked = false;
back_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  back_clicked = true;
  goBack();
  back_clicked = false;
});

var foward_clicked = false;
foward_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  foward_clicked = true;
  goFoward();
  foward_clicked = false;
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ede7e1;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 1.5;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#h1_disegna{
    text-align: center;
}
#h1_breadboard{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -550px;
}

#h1_titolo{
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
#h3_componenti_circuit{
    border-style: solid;
    width: 100px;
    border-color: black rigid 1px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color: sandybrown;
    position: relative;
    top: 85px;
}

#h3_componenti_br{
    border-style: solid;
    width: 100px;
    border-color: black rigid 1px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color: sandybrown;
    position: relative;
    top: -500px;
}

#h4_footer{
    font-size: 26px;
}


.elementi_disegno{
    position: relative;
    top: -520px;
}

#canvas{
    position: relative;
    top: -520px;
    
}

#back-button{
    position: relative;
    top: 62%;
    left: 42.5%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: rgba(244, 165, 96, 0.473);
    border-radius: 6px;
}

#foward-button{
    position: relative;
    top: 62%;
    left: 43%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: rgba(244, 165, 96, 0.473);
    border-radius: 6px;
}

#clear-button{
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
    top: 62%;
    left: 44.5%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: rgba(244, 165, 96, 0.473);
}
#components_circuit_border{
    border-style: solid;
    width: 100px;
    border-color: black rigid 1px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    cursor: move;
    position: relative;
    top: 85px;
}

#components_br_border{
    border-style: solid;
    width: 100px;
    border-color: black rigid 1px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    cursor: move;
    position: relative;
    top: -500px;
}

#components_circuit{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.footer{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: darkgray;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

.material-symbols-outlined{
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: -3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>From Circuit to Breadboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="ml2" id="h1_titolo">From Circuit to Breadboard</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="components">
            <div id="components_circuit">
                <h3 id ="h3_componenti_circuit">Componenti:</h3>
                    <ul id="components_circuit_border">
                        <li><img id ="component_circuit_resistor" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Resistor_symbol_America.svg" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                        <br><br>
                        <li><img id = "component_circuit_condensator" src="images/circuit_condensator.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                        <br><br>
                        <li><img id="component_circuit_transistor" src="images/circuit_transistor.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                        <br><br>
                        <li><img id="component_circuit_alimentator" src="images/circuit_alimentator.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                    </ul>
                <div class = "elementi_disegno">
                    <h1 id ="h1_disegna">Disegna il tuo circuito!</h1>
                <button id="back-button">Indietro
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">undo</span>
                </button>
                <button id="foward-button">Avanti
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">redo</span>
                </button>
                <button id="clear-button">Clear All
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">delete</span>
                </button>
                <canvas id = "canvas" class = "dropzone"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="components_br">
                <h1 id = "h1_breadboard">Breadboard</h1>
                <h3 id ="h3_componenti_br">Componenti:</h3>
                <ul id="components_br_border">
                    <li><img id = "component_br_resistor" src="images/br_resistor.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                    <br><br>
                    <li><img id = "component_br_condensator" src="images/br_condensator.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                    <br><br>
                    <li><img id = "component_br_transistor" src="images/br_transistor.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                    <br><br>
                    <li><img id="component_br_alimentator" src="images/br_alimentator.png" height="50" draggable="true"></li>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div>
           <h4 id ="h4_footer">Sito web progettato e realizzato da Skerdi Velo, Davide Rossini, Andrea Quagliotti <span class="material-symbols-outlined">copyright</span>2023</h4>
        </div>
    </footer>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**

For better understanding, try to drag and drop one image and you can see that the images doesn't care about the circles.

Comment: So you want the circuits (images) to snap to the holes in the breadboard (grid of circles)?

Comment: If there is any better way to do it, even without images, you're to publish it.

Comment: Yes @Mr.Polywhirl

Comment: We can't load your images so we can't see for ourselves what the effect of dragging and dropping one is. Please put at least one somewhere we can use it. And are you saying an image is to expand (or contract) to snap to the nearest two holes (as I see drawing a line does).

Comment: You can see the resistor only, check the html. If not, I'll provide the link of it https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Resistor_symbol_America.svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some researches and this code made it worked for me. Hope this helps

```
canvas.ondrop = (ev) => {
  const index = parseInt(ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
  const img = draggableImages[index];
  const circleIndex = Math.floor(ev.offsetY / 20) * NUMERO_CICLO_INTERNO + Math.floor((ev.offsetX - 13) / 25);
  const startCircle = circles[circleIndex];
  const endCircle = circles[circleIndex + 2];
  drawnImageData.push({
    img,
    x: startCircle.x - img.width / 2,
    y: startCircle.y - img.height / 2
  });
  orderStack.push(1);
};
```